# How to calculate this Gaussian integral

Tags: integration

How to calculate the below Gaussian integer?

$$\int_\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$

I know the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2n\pi}}$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: This answer is not correct. Where did you get this question from?

Comment: You can't solve this expression analytically - as far as I know.

Comment: @Peter Foreman I was trying to prove Stirling's approximation using central limit theorem, and above integral was on the middle of the proof.

Comment: @linearAlg well, I thought it is just a simple Gaussian integer problem, but wasn`t

Comment: @timedeveloper "I was trying to prove Stirling's approximation using central limit theorem" Well, [why didn't you say so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#An_alternative_derivation) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ denote the $N(0,\,1)$ distribution's pdf; let $\Phi$ denote its cdf. Your integral is$$\int_{-1/\sqrt{n}}^0\phi(x)dx=\frac12-\Phi\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac12.$$The exercise you've been given is to approximate this integral as a rectangle, whose height is the integrand's maximum on the integration range. For large $n>0$, the integrand will barely vary over the integration range, making for a good approximation. But it's certainly not exact.